# Python Webscrape

Tags: python, web-scraping

Has anyone ever had the issue where you run a script that has worked on someone elses computer but doesn't work on yours even though you are on the same network. In this case it is a webscrape for a website that is not blocked. When I run it on mine it returns an error of - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Appreciate anyones help.

I've tried manipulating the proxy entries with no success.

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing us the code, or the full error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.